# Can't get data from a firestore collection - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an Angular project linked with firestore database.
To make it short, the pages are stored in the db and I created a PageComponent which shows a URL like this : page/'id' and displays the linked id page.
I'm using functions from a service that are working on others components but for some reason I just can't get anything else than the page's id.

Here's my ts :

```
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {
  auth = this.admin.auth;
  id: string = '';
  page: Page = {
    id: '',
    titre: '',
    contenu: '',
  };
  constructor(
    private pagesservice: PagesService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private admin: AdminLoginService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id') as string;
    if (this.id) {
      this.pagesservice.getPage(this.id).subscribe((p) => {
        this.page = p;
      });
    }
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(this.page);
  }
}
```

And this is the service:

```
export class PagesService {
  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private admin: AdminLoginService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  getPages(): Observable<Page[]> {
    //POUR A VOIR L'ID
    return this.afs
      .collection<Page>('pages')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map((changes: any) =>
          changes.map((c: any) => ({
            id: c.payload.doc.id,
            ...c.payload.doc.data(),
          }))
        )
      );
  }
  //RECUPERE UN ARTICLE
  getPage(id: string): Observable<Page> {
    return this.afs
      .collection<Page>('pages')
      .doc(id)
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map((action: any) => {
          if (action.payload.exists === false) {
            return new Object() as Page;
          } else {
            const data = action.payload.data() as Page;
            data.id = action.payload.id;
            return data;
          }
        })
      );
  }
  //AJOUTE UN ARTICLE
  addPage(page: Page): void {
    this.afs.collection<Page>('pages').add(page);
  }
  // MODIFIE L'ARTICLE
  updatePage(page: Page, pageId: string): void {
    this.afs.collection<Page>('pages').doc(pageId).update(page);
  }
  // SUPPRIME L'ARTICLE
  deletePage(pageId: string): void {
    if (confirm('Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer cette page?')) {
      this.afs.collection<Page>('pages').doc(pageId).delete();
      this.admin.showNotification('Page supprimée !');
      this.router.navigate(['dashboard/pages']);
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['pages-form/{{o.id}}']);
    }
  }
}
```

And here's what i get from the ngOninit's console.log:

```
// console.log(this.id)
b 

// console.log(this.page)
Object { id: "", titre: "", contenu: "" }
​
contenu: ""
​
id: ""
​
titre: ""
```

Here's the admin edit component where the function is working fine :
TS :

```
export class PagesFormComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string = '';

  page: Page = {
    id: '',
    titre: '',
    //image: '',
    contenu: '',
  };

  constructor(
    public pagesservice: PagesService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private admin: AdminLoginService
  ) {}
  save(pageForm: NgForm) {
    if (pageForm.valid) {
      if (this.page.id) {
        this.pagesservice.updatePage(pageForm.value, this.id);
        this.admin.showNotification('Page modifiée !');
      } else {
        this.pagesservice.addPage(pageForm.value);
        this.admin.showNotification('La page a été créé');
      }

      this.router.navigate(['dashboard/pages']);
    } else {
      this.admin.showNotification('Il y a des erreurs dans le formulaire!');
    }
  }

  delete() {
    this.pagesservice.deletePage(this.id);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id') as string;
    if (this.id)
      this.pagesservice.getPage(this.id).subscribe((p) => (this.page = p));
  }
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="container-fluid p-5">
    <form #pageForm="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="titre"><h2>Titre</h2></label>
            <input #titreInput="ngModel" type="text" name="titre" id="titre" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : titreInput.invalid && titreInput.touched}" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="page.titre" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="titreInput?.hasError('required')">
                <strong>Le titre est obligatoire</strong>
            </mat-error>
        </div>


        <div class="md-form amber-textarea active-amber-textarea-2">

            <label for="contenu"><h2>Contenu</h2></label>
            <textarea #contenuInput="ngModel" type="textarea" name="contenu" id="contenu" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : contenuInput.invalid&&contenuInput.touched}" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="page.contenu" requiredmatInput cdkTextareaAutosize #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize"
                cdkAutosizeMinRows="1" cdkAutosizeMaxRows="5"></textarea>

            <mat-error fxFill *ngIf="contenuInput?.hasError('required')"><strong>Contenu obligatoire</strong></mat-error>
        </div>



        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-1" (click)="save(pageForm)">Enregistrer</button>
        <button [hidden]="id === null" (click)="delete()" class="btn tbn-danger m-1">Supprimer</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The service is working on other components to get the data to autofill a editing form so I'm wondering what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Beware of this:

```
 if (this.id) {
      this.pagesservice.getPage(this.id)
      .subscribe((p) => {
        this.page = p; // <==== After this exactly point is when you are going to have the data in 'this.page', not before        
        console.log(this.page);// <=== This console is going to work fine
      });
    }
    console.log(this.id);
    // console.log(this.page); // Here, this.page don't have any data yet.
```

The reason this happens is because 'getPage' method is **asynchronous**, and you get data inside the subscribe (when the subscribe gets the response).
However, the *execution thread* does not stand still in the ".subscribe", and before subscribe have the response, the code gets to your last instruction ( console.log(this.page);) and this.page has not data yet.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i did  the console.log in the brackets but it still returns an empty object.
I'll put another component where the function is working in the main post.